# Xcode 13 & Flutter 2.5.1 - fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, xcode13

I just started getting this issue after upgrading to `Xcode 13`. I upgraded `Flutter` to `2.5.1` a few days before.

This is what I am seeing:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AA0EE6D2-4E24-48C6-B9D6-4F2598B68E4E, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:765C02E6-837E-4443-9073-722162C490DC, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:30429B61-93BC-4497-B556-3639373A10D0, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:57217E13-F700-4673-9ABF-1866BAE1E435, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A85DD0A6-EA0F-480C-9A6F-07966F4FE66B, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1D568B75-852B-42BE-8178-C39E6C515C41, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:347466A9-6BA4-4674-94B6-BCB3ACB11F00, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F74B444A-2838-4920-91DB-83893719250E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2D4AF847-04A7-463C-A46C-D5D1E200CFDC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BCD3D3BD-6485-4575-AA35-BF9ADEEBB4BD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:06DE013F-BF48-4857-B952-BFC2AA1BD304, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8A06D628-6132-4558-BB65-5598FFAC98DC, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:885B1C8A-0497-4D95-8A87-447E40AB9238, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FF519331-8490-4219-92D0-ED9A08F11976, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:51671583-ED36-4330-839B-401BA09B3996, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:950FC388-6567-40BD-AD31-6CC5A334AC97, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:562728AB-E0CA-4675-BF75-787299ECE105, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CBB3D2FF-97DF-4328-8AD0-7350F83989D1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D99FD6E3-C6DC-4F16-8092-83EA0216367F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2A06C9C4-9D8C-4C9B-9620-12265131A747, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EA2B1A03-78F8-42B2-9818-41FE3F1E833A, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/abc/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock-0.5.2/ios/Classes/messages.m:4:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

I have tried re-installing Flutter, deleting and re-cloning my project, removing the pods, flutter clean + pod install, flutter cache repair, and removing Flutter from the project and re-adding.

Each of these results in some variation of the error above.

I also had to make a change in my `Podfile` --

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
   end
  end
 end
```

If I revert this back then I get a different set of errors where some pods are complaining about being set to 8.0 and need to be 9.0 to 14.9.9.

I tried changing the individual pods in the Runner project but that doesn't work. The above clear out that error but now I am faced with the other.

To note, Android works fine. It's just iOS.

Any other suggestions for this one?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

In Podfile:
Replace

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
   end
  end
 end
```

By

```
post_install do |installer| 
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) 
  end 
end
```

Then open iOS file in Xcode, and in Pods, for each Target, in Build Settings, set deployment target to 11 (maybe 9 is enough)

Is this what you tried already ?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with XCode 13 and Flutter 2.5.3: building via xcodebuild gave error (building from UI works ok) for random modules. After I tried to remove 'problematic' library - error was against next random library until I got stuck to Flutter.h.

My problem was that during solving issues I changed the deployment target to 13 in XCode but made a mess: I updated it in *Podfile*, *Project->Runner->Info*, *Project->Runner->Build settings*, but forgot to do it for *Targets->Runner->Build Settings*.

Once I've updated *Targets->Runner->Build Settings* as well it started to compile successfully.

Eventually I've rolledback to Target 11.0 in all places and it still compiles.